# Thrown error in promisified ExpressJs function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bluebird

I'm not quite sure I understand how errors are handled in promises (and I'm fairly new to promises so I'm likely not using them to their full potential).

I have the following code:

```
app.listenAsync = Promise.promisify(app.listen);

app.listenAsync(config.port)
.then(function done() {
    console.log("We're listening!");
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log("Abort abort!");
});
```

For a reason I don't quite understand, my `catch()` is never called, even if app.listenAsync throws an error, EADDRINUSE for instance. Why?

**Edit**: 
I just noticed that if I do

```
var listenAsync = Promise.promisify(app.listen);

listenAsync(config.port)
    .then(function done() {
        console.log("We're listening!");
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log("Abort abort!");
    });
```

Gives almost the correct behaviour. listenAsync throws an error (that is caught in the `catch` statement this time) `Possibly unhandled TypeError: listener must be a function`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried using `Promise` object as usal, like 
   `new Promise(function (reslve, reject) {
      try  { app.listen(config.port); resolve(); }
      catch () {reject();}
   }).then(...).catch(...)` ?

Comment: Please give full code, also just in case what bluebird version are you using?

Comment: Bluebird 2.9.9
Full code: http://pastie.org/9960184
My apologies for the delay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with promises, it's just basic javascript: you are calling listen as if it was a function but it's a method of `app`.

Some options:

```
Promise.promisifyAll(app);
// Note how it's called as a method on app
app.listenAsync(...).then(....)
```

Or

```
// Bind the function as a method of app
var appListenAsync = Promise.promisify(app.listen, app);
appListenAsync(...).then(....)
```